# Does this poem stand up to the rules of poetry?

Tags: poetry, feedback

This is pretty much my first poem(I think this counts as one), about a tentacle monster keeping a schoolgirl asleep in a dream. It is titled 'The Beast From The East' Here it is:

> "THE TENTACLED TERROR
>
> THE TENTACLE BEARER
>
> THE BEAST FROM THE EAST........HAS LONG BEEN RELEASED
>
> AND FOR 28 YEARS AT LEAST, YOU HAVE HAVE BEEN LONG ASLEEP
>
> AND IN THAT TIME YOU HAVE NOT EVEN CAUGHT A PEEP OF THE TRUE REALITY
> SO TO SPEAK
>
> WE ADORE YOU BUT HE ABHORS YOU, SO HE PLANS TO KEEP YOU OH SO FAST
> ASLEEP UNTIL EVEN THE END OF TIME DECIDES TO TAKE A PEAK
>
> SO MAYBE TO WAKE UP.......YOU JUST NEED A SHAKEUP, SO KNOW THAT YOUR
> LIFE IS BUT A DREAM
>
> SO LITTLE MISS JACOB, WILL YOU PLEASE NOW WAKE UP!!!!!!!"

Does it hold up in terms of rhyme and whatnot?

Comment: What "rules of poetry" are you referring to?

Comment: Like rhyme or timing. I am not really that deep into poetry, so forgive me if I use the wrong terms. @F1Krazy

Comment: Is it artistic intention that it's all in Caps lock? I can't bring myself to read more than some two lines.

Comment: The rules apply to poems written to a set pattern. Yours obviously isn't, as the lines vary wildly in length, so it doesn't matter. (NB it's 'take a peek', not 'peak'.)

Comment: Bad Poetry Alert: it's overloaded with **'careless idioms'** cliché phrases with no relation to tone or context or narrative voice ("life is but a dream" "the end of time") – even worse, some are **Malaprops** substituting a similar-sounding word with the wrong meaning ("caught a peep" "shakeup"). Allcaps and seven exclamation marks in a row cannot create a feeling of urgency and danger when the rest of it is a sing-song patchwork of Motown lyrics. (The idea is cool, but who is speaking? What 'schoolgirl' is 28yrs old?)

Comment: Ok, I agree it could be better, but some of your points are not clear(to me)/wrong: In what way are these not related to the tone or context or narrative voice? From what I understand I used peep correctly, I guess shakeup might be a bit wrong, but it kind of fits. What do mean by Motown lyrics?  I guess the people trying to wake her up and she is still teenaged as she is being pumped with immortality substance from the monster(this has/will have a story it goes to). @wetcircuit

Comment: a definition of 'careless idoms' which you can't take personally: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/poetry-clichés-avoid-like-plague-ronnie-l-smith

Answer (score 1):

> Roses a Red
>
> Violets are blue
>
> Some poems rhyme
>
> But this one don't
>
> -My Father

Poems do not have to rhyme.  The Haiku, for example, rarely has a rhyme and instead favors a syllabic consistent (Three Lines 5/7/5 syllables per line.  It's not that they cannot rhyme, but that the genre is generally in the Japanese language and rhymes rarely translate.).

Over all you have a good start, but there are some glaring problems.  To work on your rhyming, rewrite this so that each line of your poem such that:

> "THE TENTACLED TERROR (A)
>
> THE TENTACLE BEARER (A)
>
> THE BEAST FROM THE EAST (B)
>
> HAS LONG BEEN RELEASED (C)
>
> AND FOR 28 YEARS AT LEAST (B)
>
> YOU HAVE HAVE BEEN LONG ASLEEP (D)
>
> AND IN THAT TIME YOU HAVE NOT EVEN CAUGHT A PEEP (D)
>
> OF THE TRUE REALITY SO TO SPEAK (E)
>
> WE ADORE YOU (F*)
>
> BUT HE ABHORS YOU (F*)
>
> SO HE PLANS TO KEEP YOU (G*)
>
> OH SO FAST ASLEEP (D)
>
> UNTIL EVEN THE END OF TIME DECIDES TO TAKE A PEAK (E)
>
> SO MAYBE TO WAKE UP (H)
>
> YOU JUST NEED A SHAKEUP (H)
>
> SO KNOW THAT YOUR LIFE IS BUT A DREAM (I)
>
> SO LITTLE MISS JACOB (H)
>
> WILL YOU PLEASE NOW WAKE UP (H)

You'll noticed I gave each line a letter.  This letter denotes seperate rhyming patterns.   In the case of letters marked with an asterisk (*) I believe you were trying to rhyme "you" with itself.  As a general rule, when the rhyming word is the same, the word preceeding it is part of the rhyme, which is why I marked "Adore you/ Abhors You" as (F) but "Keep you" as (G).   Keep you does not rhyme with Adore you.

Generally, the letters should be arranged in a pattern i.e.:

> A
> B
> A
> B
>
> C
> D
> C
> D

It doesn't have to be this pattern, but they rhymes should be consistent.

Another thing to look out for is the meter/metre (depending on which English you use) which is the rhythmic structure of a verse or a line in a verse (in our above example, a line is one of the letters... a verse would be the four lines.).  To get an idea of rhythmic structure in action, take the begining of this Poem (Casey at the Bat):

> The outlook wasn't brilliant for
> The Mudville Nine that day;
> The score stood four to two, with but
> One inning more to play.

And sing it to the tune of "Amazing Grace":

> Amazing Grace, how sweet the sound,
> That saved a wretch like me!
> I once was lost, but now am found,
> Was blind, but now I see.

Now personally, I find "Amazing Grace" to be a sad remorseful song for a funeral, but the lyrics are quite badass (It's an academic term).   So let's jazz it up.  Now, take the lyrics of Amazing Grace and sing them to the tune of this number (Do your own acapella musical instrument where needed):

> I wanna be the very best
> Like no one ever was
> To catch them is my real test
> To train them is my cause

You'll notice that despite the different subjects of the poem and the different rhyme schemes, all three poems are written that their words can be inter-changed with each other despite each being 110+ years older than the more recent (Amazing Grace was published in 1772, Casey at the Bat was in 1888 and The Pokemon Theme was 1998) and their vastly different topics (The power of the Grace of God, Losing a Baseball Game due to a player's hubris, a 30 minute commercial for a video game targeting a Saturday morning television audience.).  What do they have in common?

The meter.  No, really, this particular meter is called the common meter because, well, in English... it's rediculously common.  It's used in Emily Dickison poems (there's a minor trend of doing her poems, most of which are dark and morose to the tune of Pokemon), The Ballad of Gilligan's Island (actually a Ballard Meter, which is a more strict Common Meter), the theme to Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles, House of the Rising Sun (There is a house in New Orleans/ It's called The Rising Sun), and "America the Beautiful" to name a few famous works that use it (Really bad ass, sing Pokemon to tune of Rising Sun).

As such, poetry is immensely complicated to write (I dabble... and mostly it's to make parodies of pop songs, and it's tough.).  There's a lot more to it then just rhyming things.  Hope this helps

P.S. There is no single word that rhymes with "orange" but "poor hinge" will do in a pinch. (The reason for this is the word "orange" is very new to the language... being a Arabic loan word that entered in the early 1500s to describe the color, since English did not have a word for the color.  We used to call it "Red-Yellow" or "Yellow-Red").  The color is literally named for the fruit.